# Qt 5.1 OpenGL widget inside a window

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

How do I add an OpenGL widget into my window (QMainWindow) in Qt 5.1? Seems like I shouldn't use QGLWidget since it's deprecated and the examples in Qt website create a window that is OpenGL-only, not an OpenGL context in a widget inside a window. I'm using C++ and I create the UI using Qt Designer.

Comment: it's basically as described in [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/). For everything else you just read the docs of the related classe. I'd use a `QWindow`, call `setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface)` before `create()` and then create a new `QOpenGLContext` and use its `makeCurrent()` function to pass your `QWindow` to it.  For an easier solution wait for [5.2.0](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31771?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab)

Comment: also, read [this discussion](http://www.marshut.com/qiskx/qt-5-2.html)  to see that the deprecation may have been one minor version too soon.

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can perfectly use QGLWidget...

Comment: See here for a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983107/how-can-qwindow-replace-qglwidget