# How can QWindow replace QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

QT docs say that since qt5 you should use the QOpenGL* classes instead of QGL*.

Problem is there is no QGLWidget replacement. I figured out that instead you should use QWindow in conjunction with QOpenGLContext and a call to setSurfaceType( OpenGLSurface );.

Only problem is that a QWindow can't have QWidget as parent. So how can I embed a QWindow aka. my OpenGL drawing surface into other widgets?

Comment: I'm going to quote another comment of mine: it's basically as described in [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/). For everything else you just read the docs of the related classes. I'd use a QWindow, call setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface) before create() and then create a new QOpenGLContext and use its makeCurrent() function to pass your QWindow to it. For an easier solution wait for [5.2.0](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31771?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab).

Comment: also, read [this discussion](http://www.marshut.com/qiskx/qt-5-2.html) to see that the deprecation may have been one minor version too soon.

Comment: @PeterT Could you perhaps work that into an answer?

Comment: @Bart I didn't just want to post a few links and plug that as an answer but I'm going to copy out some code snippets from the posts and make that an answer

Comment: Unfortunately they didn't added the OpenGLWidget with 5.2 -_-

Comment: @Alexander preliminary support (undocumented) will be in 5.3 and actual release will be in 5.4, it's work in progress at the moment as you can see [here (header)](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/f4044e853cdb66a7f7f7e61df78434243b85b03d:src/widgets/kernel/qopenglwidget_p.h) and [here (source)](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/f4044e853cdb66a7f7f7e61df78434243b85b03d:src/widgets/kernel/qopenglwidget.cpp). (The links I posted will stay the same, so they will probably not reflect the status of progress if you're reading this at a later date)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

QT 5.1 is in a weird situation OpenGL and `QWidget` (and derived) wise. There's no `QGLWidget` replacement yet all other QGL classes have clear replacements.

If you don't want to use the old `QGLWidget` you indeed have to manufacture yourself a replacement with `QWindow`. So, first you set up your `QWindow` then, as you correctly said call `setSurfaceType( OpenGLSurface );` before you call `create();` on it. Then you create a new `QOpenGLContext` and use its `makeCurrent()` function and pass your `QWindow`. Then you create a `QWidget` from the `QWindow` using [`QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);`](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/)

But this is only a temporary hack, that you shouldn't have to use unless you actually want to mix QtQuick an QWidget. You can then replace this temporary hack with the actual replacement in <s>5.2.0</s> [**5.4.0**](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36899) called [QOpenGLWidget](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31771)

Comment: +1 and thanks for that. You had all the information there and I thought it would be a bit pointless for me to essentially state the same.

Comment: In the code I try to port there are events overwritten and the paint, update method etc. I guess there is no easy way in porting that behavior?

Comment: @Alexander I would suggest that you wait until 5.2.0 if you want to minimize your workload. If you are itching to do it now, look at the [OpenGLWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/openglwindow.html) example in the docs

Comment: I would wait. But I have to port the project to OS X before october.

Comment: Is QOpenGLWidget actually implemented in Qt 5.2? Your links to QOpenGLWidget ticket states it is still unresolved. If that's so, your last paragraph may be misleading.

Comment: @Korchkidu yep, looks like they're trying to find another solution, well it was not a release blocking ticket after all. They're focusing a lot on mobile at the moment it seems.