# How to get an openGL canvas in qt 5.3.2 < 5.4?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am attempting to write a qt 5.3.2 application with a main window that has a rectangular section showing an openGl content.

Browsing the internet I found approaches.

First among them is the *QGLWidget*. However, it appears to be obsolete: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QGLWidget.html

Sadly the site does not state an alternative, so I browsed on and found Qt 5.4's *QOpenGLWidget* at https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.4/qopenglwidget.html

However, being a Debian lover I appear to be stuck with Qt 5.3.2 < 5.4 which is minimum for that class.

On this forum I also found [How can QWindow replace QGLWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983107/how-can-qwindow-replace-qglwidget) which was asked more than a year ago and even has an accepted answer. But first I have to admit I do not understand it plus the author states it is a 'temporary hack' at best.

I guess I could dedicate a new window for the openGL content... but is there really no other recommended way for a user of qt 5.3?

Comment: You could always download Qt 5.4 source and compile it yourself: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: `QGLWidget` has indeed been deprecated, but only because `QOpenGLWidget` has been created as a successor.  So if you're using a version of Qt before `QOpenGLWidget` was introduced, then `QGLWidget` is what you should be using.  Is there any particular reason why you can't add a more up to date repo to your distro?

Comment: @KuramaYoko, that would be an option... but how would it say it to my CMakeLists.txt?... googling... maybe using something like http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html

Comment: @cmannett85: Yes, there is. As stated on https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-dev-tools I would have to dare the experimental branch in order to get 5.4. I truly love Debian for its consequent stability policy. However, stuff like this is the downside.